# Arista 7050S BGP Over Management Port not working

Tags: arista

i have an Arista 7050s with eos 4.18.1.1F and i have bgp over my management port with my management router (its a VPN router that out staff connect to this router and use our internal router)
here is my route :

```
VRF name: default
Codes: C - connected, S - static, K - kernel,
       O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area, E1 - OSPF external type 1,
       E2 - OSPF external type 2, N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1,
       N2 - OSPF NSSA external type2, B I - iBGP, B E - eBGP,
       R - RIP, I L1 - ISIS level 1, I L2 - ISIS level 2,
       O3 - OSPFv3, A B - BGP Aggregate, A O - OSPF Summary,
       NG - Nexthop Group Static Route, V - VXLAN Control Service

 B E    5.x.x.0/28 [200/0] via 172.x.x.209, Management1
```

and i have a server behind this arista when i want to ping 5.x.x.1 it seems the route is not working and when i do tcpdump on arista on Ma1 port there is no icmp traffic,
i guess arista does not route traffic over Ma1 port, does not it?
any idea on this?
thank you.

Comment: i just move my routing to another port and it works! it seems arista does not route towards Ma1 , does not it?

Comment: Generally speaking most enterprise network equipment does not allow transit traffic on the management interface. The management interfaces are only intended for basic management access and usually not part of the same ASICS used for forwarding.

Answer (score 2):

Arista, like most, if not all, vendors does not support routing/forwrding on MA intfs.